# k nearest neighbour search for cells in place of matrices?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, classification, nearest-neighbor, knn

I want to find the euclidean distance between some datasets. For each class I have about 50 learning or training samples and 5 test samples. The problem is that this data for each sample is stored in cells and is in the `m * n` format rather than the preferred `1 * n` format.

I see that matlab has a built in function for k nearest neighbours using euclidean distance; [knnsearch](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html). But the problem is that it expects the samples to be in the form of rows and columns. It gives an error when data in cells are provided.

Is there anyway to do this classification in the format my data is in? Or is it preferred that I convert them to 1-D format (maybe by using some sort of dimensionality reduction?)

Suppose there are 5 classes/models that are each represented by cells of size `32 * N`, below is a screenshot from Matlab. Each cell represents the features of a lot of training images, so cell 1 is a representation of person 1 and so on.

[image]

Now similarly I have test images that need to be identified. The features of each test image are also in cells. So I have 10 unknown images with their features extracted and stored in cells. Each cell is a representation of a single unknown image. Below again is a screenshot from Matlab showing their dimensions
[image]

As can be seen they are all of varying dimensions. I know this is not the ideal format of KNN as here each image is represented by a multidimension matrix rather than a single row of variables. How do I perform euclidean distance on such data?

Thank you

Comment: How do you expect to perform `k` nearest neighbour with cells?  Can you show us an example of what the input data is and how you'd expect the distance to be measured?  I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding your problem statement.

Comment: I'm also having a bit of trouble understanding. If your data are in cells but every observation has the same number of variables, then you can convert to an MxN matrix with `cell2mat` and then use `knnsearch` (which is happy to take an MxN matrix).

If you're using cells because you don't have uniform data, then it's tricky to define (and thus find) a nearest neighbor.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I have added details, hope this clarifies my situation